# Angular Dynamic Nested Array Not Displaying Error

Tags: angular, validation, multidimensional-array, error-handling, formbuilder

I have the following nested array working perfect, except the second and third level down will not display the error message from the Validators.  I think it has something to do with returning the value so it would return the object and not display a 'null' error.  Any help is appreciated.

**component.ts**

```js
constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private crudService: CrudService
  ) { 
    this.portfolioForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      program_title: ['', Validators.required],
      ...
    })
  }
  
addProject() {
    let control = <FormArray>this.portfolioForm.controls.projects;
    control.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        project_title: ['', Validators.required],
        ...
      })
    )
  }
```

**component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="portfolioForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row pl-3 pr-3">
    <div class="col-7 card-body widget-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textarea">Program Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm checking-field" formControlName="program_title" required>
        <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="portfolioForm.get('program_title').touched && portfolioForm.get('program_title').hasError('required')">Title is required</span>                              
                    

...

  <div formArrayName="projects">
    <div *ngFor="let project of portfolioForm.get('projects')['controls']; let i=index">
      <fieldset>
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="row pl-3 pr-3">
            <div class="col-1 card-body"></div>
              <div class="col-6 card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="textarea">Project {{i+1}} Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm checking-field" formControlName="project_title" required>
                  <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="portfolioForm.get('project_title') && portfolioForm.get('project_title').touched && portfolioForm.get('project_title').hasError('required')">Title is required</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to dynamically check, and plug it into your title *ngIf

```
subProjectTitleError(form: FormGroup, i: number, j: number): boolean {     return form.dirty && this.portfolioForm.get('projects').get(String(i)).get('subprojects').get(String(j)).get('subproject_title').value === ''   }
```

Comment: I could not get it to work using that, but created a quick and dirty StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ckczn9

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1m6flg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You have some intense nesting going on. Not sure if it is required to have all every array "push" instance be a formGroup. You can probably just push controls onto that form = to the previous name + iteration number.

Here is how you would drill into that value to check if it is valid:
`this.portfolioForm.get('projects').get('0').get('subprojects').get('0').`
`get('subproject_title').value === ''`

This is grabbing the 0 index, you'd have to add your i / j variables respectively.

Comment: It's helpful to console your form in each instance and follow it all the way down the line.

Comment: Thanks.  Did you try that in StackBlitz?  I still can't get the error to to display for projects or subprojects.

Comment: Yep, it's working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1m6flg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I appreciate all your help with this.  It current displays the error though without prompt and only works for the first iteration.  Is there a way it can be displayed for all iterations (objects) and only when 'touched'?

Comment: No problem. Forms can be tricky :)
Here is the updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1m6flg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Added this method to handle that:
`subProjectTitleError(form: FormGroup, i: number, j: number): boolean` 
`{
    return form.dirty && this.portfolioForm.get('projects').get(String(i)).get('subprojects').get(String(j)).get('subproject_title').value === ''
  }`

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working in the StackBlitz nor my code.  It also seems like a lot to add that in the TS component for each field.  The odd part about the whole thing is that the error message doesn't display in the project or subproject fields because "portfolioForm.get('project_title')" is needed to not return a null value.  Otherwise it doesn't work at all.  Look how it works perfectly for the program field without that syntax.